# Annotate that `__init__` get argument of type, declared in class variable

Tags: python, type-hinting

I'm trying to implement type hinting for situations, when we have a `Base` class, which implement `__init__` method and expect some `obj` of type `Base.obj_type` and in sub-classes expect type `SubClass.obj_type`

Something like that:

```py
class Base:
    obj_type = int

    def __init__(self, obj: 'obj_type'):
        self.obj = obj


class A(Base):
    object_type = str



A(1). # I want to get type check error here, because A expect str type for obj
```

I can achieve this by override `__init__` in subclass, but there is another way to get this? Thanks for your help!

UPD.
One of the possible solution, which I found based on `typing.Generic`. But, unfortunately, that's not force type checking on PyCharm, only `mypy` understand it correctly.

```py
import typing as t

T = t.TypeVar("T")

class Base(t.Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, obj: T):
        self.obj = obj

class A(Base[str]):
    pass

a = A(1)
```

mypy error: `error: Argument 1 to "A" has incompatible type "int"; expected "str"`

Comment: `Generic` is probably the orthodox way of doing this. The PyCharm built-in type checker is somewhat limited, but there's a mypy plugin available.